# If $f(g(g(f(x)))) = x$ then does $f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S$ be a set and $f, g: S \to S$ such that for all $x \in S$, $f(g(g(f(x)))) = x$. Is it true that for all $x \in S$, $f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $g(x) = -x$ and $f(x) = x/(x-1)$ (on a suitable $S$ where you won't end up dividing by $0$, e.g. the irrationals).